# animating object along a path in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to animate an object along a path. I am doing so by creating an animation like:[image].

This works great but since my terrain is not flat it will be nice if I don't have to deal with the y component. In other words I want to move an object along the x-axis and z-axis and if there is a small slope increase then increase the object y position. same thing if there is a downward slope. Or maybe I have to create a script where it checks to see if the object is colliding with the terrain. if not then decrease its y position. I don't know if this will work meanwhile animating an object though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way I can think of to solve this is for you to make the object a rigid body and use collision (probably a mesh or capsule collider if its a player character) to get it to sit on the floor.

[image: Screenshot]